# How to build open SSL for android in Ubuntu for dummies

Tags: android, qt, openssl

Hello i am trying to package openSSL for my qt android project in windows, and inorder for me to get the neccesary libraries (libcrypto.so and libssl.so). So i went ahead and installed a ubuntu virtual machine so i could build the libraries using the methods here

https://bibuweb.de/2018/11/17/building-openssl-for-qt-and-android/

I am currently stuck on `Build OpenSsl` part. Where do i run the command inside the extracted folder of openSSL.1.0.2 ? if so ./Configure android shared throws an unknown file directory error

and futher more if i do finish building openSSL where are these build libraries located.

I am very very new to Linux, it would be appreciated if you can explain it like you are explaining it to a dummy :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope its obvious for you that Linux libraries are not compatible with windows.

The article you referred to describes howto cross compile openssl for Android!

If you want to compile openssl for Linux check [openssl.org](https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html)

May be for Ubuntu there is a precompiled 1.0.2 package. Please check the Ubuntu community.
Or check [this](https://gist.github.com/mbejda/a1dabc45b32aaf8b25ae5e8d05923518)

Comment: yes  it is what i am try to achieve, i am just having trouble producing results right now